# How can I check with TGM php library if my dependency requirements were fulfilled?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using TGM library for wordpress plugin development, where I'm declaring other plugins as requirements.

It´s working OK. Once I activate my plugin, the other required ones are being requested for installation, but I don't know how to check if they were actually installed and enabled by the user, so I can really start my plugin's functions.

Comment: I don't get it, after being installed, the other plugins shouldn't be *requested* anymore... that's when you start your plugin's functions `if($requirementNotInstalled) request(); else work_normally();`. Ps: I'm not familiar with TGM.

Comment: TGM has a function where you declare your dependencies, but i wasn't able to find a place to check if these dependencies were fulfilled. So if i don't check, it could generate errors in case these plugins weren't installed and activated yet